# How to use item count in ListView.Builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Click Here for Image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBuKU.png) [Click here to see error when i input 'itemCount'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1oe0.png) I want to ask, I am having trouble using the List.builder () feature. where I can't limit the data contained in the list so that it will display an error message about the error range. Here is the source code that I gave.

```
  _sort = <Sort>[
  Sort(
      category: 'By Games',
      item: new Container(
          height: 200,
          child: new Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            //itemCount: allGames['games'].length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Text(allGames['games'][index]['game_title'].toString(), style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              );
            },
          )))),
```

and here i call the 'Category' and 'Item'. I wrap it in a wrap widget. then for categories, I did divide it into 3 parts. then every part in the category I named 'items' and the problem is the items here have excess capacity so that the data displayed is leftover and not on target.

```
                                                            child: Wrap(
                                                            children: <Widget>[
                                                              ListView.builder(
                                                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                                                itemCount: 3,
                                                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                                  context = context;
                                                                  if (index < 2) {
                                                                    final sort = _sort[index];
                                                                    return ExpansionTile(
                                                                      title: ListTile(
                                                                        title: Text(
                                                                          sort.category,
                                                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                                                        ),
                                                                      ),
                                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                                        ListTile(
                                                                          title: sort.item,
                                                                        )
                                                                      ],
                                                                    );
                                                                  } else {



                                                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing `allGames["games"]` and it says that you're trying to use `[]` on `null`.

Seems like `allGames` is `null`, so put an eye on that.

Other than that, your use of `itemCount` is fine!

You can add some null awareness by doing something like this:

```
itemCount = allGames != null ? (allGames["games"]?.length ?? 0) : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when the build method runs at the first time, your allGames is null. So, try to add a default value, for example:

```
itemCount: allGames['games'].length ?? 0
```

Comment: this will crash because allGames is null and the subscript operator will be applied to null.